# Redux action return type when using dispatch and getState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I am struggling to figure out what the return type should be for my action. Everything works whilst I am using `any` but am trying to avoid using `any`.

```
export const saveValue = (value: number): any => {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => State): void => {
        axios.post('www.exampleurl.com', value)
            .then((response) => {
                const someValueFromState = getState().stateValue;
                const payload = {...response, someValueFromState}
                dispatch({ type: constants.SAVE_VALUE, payload });
            });
    };
};
```

I had it working before when the action was not using `getState()` and it looked like this, where it returned `Dispatch<SaveValue>`:

```
export const saveValue = (value: number): Dispatch<SaveValue> => {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>): void => {
        axios.post('www.exampleurl.com', value)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({ type: constants.SAVE_VALUE, response });
            });
    };
};
```

But once I added getState, I am not sure what to do anymore. I have tried to put the return value in a variable and can see the object I am creating is `const myAttempt: (dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => State) => void` but when I tried to use it as follows, it doesn't work:

```
export const saveValue = (value: number): (dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => StoreState) => void => {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => State): void => {
        axios.post('www.exampleurl.com', value)
            .then((response) => {
                const someValueFromState = getState().stateValue;
                const payload = {...response, someValueFromState}
                dispatch({ type: constants.SAVE_VALUE, payload });
            });
    };
};
```

Doing this, I get an error: `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

EDIT:

Just to add, I cannot return `Dispatch<SaveValue>` as I was before, otherwise I get this error: `Type '(dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => State) => void' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SaveValue>'`

Comment: I guess you still only need `export const saveValue = (value: number): Dispatch<SaveValue> => {`

Comment: When I do that it says `Type '(dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => State) => void' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SaveValue>'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A friend helped me answer this. This was the right way to do it:

```
export const saveValue = (value: number): (dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => State): void => {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => State): void => {
        axios.post('www.exampleurl.com', value)
            .then((response) => {
                const someValueFromState = getState().stateValue;
                const payload = {...response, someValueFromState}
                dispatch({ type: constants.SAVE_VALUE, payload });
            });
    };
};
```

The issue I was having was with my `mapDispatchToProps` function which was being explicitly typed and causing the error `Type '(dispatch: Dispatch<SaveVisit>, getState: () => StoreState) => void' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SaveVisit>'`. The function was:

```
interface MapDispatchToPropsInterface {
    saveValue : (value: number) => Dispatch<SaveValue>;
}

const mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsInterface = {
    saveValue : ActionCreators.saveValue,
};
```

but the interface needed to be:

```
interface MapDispatchToPropsInterface {
    saveValue : (saveDetails: CheckedVisit) =>  (dispatch: Dispatch<SaveValue>, getState: () => StoreState) => void;
}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error around `: void =>` on the first line when I try this. It seems like using react-redux's built in `ThunkAction` is the correct approach. [Relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63881398/how-to-properly-type-a-thunk-with-thunkaction-using-redux-thunk-in-typescript).

Answer (score 5):

First configure the following in your store:

```
// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

then, in your function use the previously custom types

```
export const getUserRolUid = () => {
    return async (dispatch: AppDispatch, getState: ()=> RootState) => {

      const { uid } = getState().auth;
      const user = await loadUser(uid);
      
      if (user) {
        // update the role and send the data to redux
        dispatch(getUser(user));
      } else {
        dispatch(getUserRolUid());
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: solve my problem