# How to properly type a thunk with ThunkAction using redux-thunk in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings, redux-thunk

I'm trying to type check my `redux-thunk` code with Typescript.

From the official docs of Redux: [Usage with Redux Thunk](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-redux-thunk), we get this example:

```
// src/thunks.ts

import { Action } from 'redux'
import { sendMessage } from './store/chat/actions'
import { RootState } from './store'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

export const thunkSendMessage = (
  message: string
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
  const asyncResp = await exampleAPI()
  dispatch(
    sendMessage({
      message,
      user: asyncResp,
      timestamp: new Date().getTime()
    })
  )
}

function exampleAPI() {
  return Promise.resolve('Async Chat Bot')
}
```

*To reduce repetition, you might want to define a reusable AppThunk type once, in your store file, and then use that type whenever you write a thunk:*

```
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>
```

**QUESTION**

I'm not fully understanding the use of the `ThunkAction` type:

```
ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>>
```

There are 4 type params, right?

**1st** - `void`

This is the return type of the thunk, right? Shouldn't it be `Promise<void>`, since it's `async`?

**2nd** - `RootState`

It's the full state shape, right? I mean, it's not a slice, but the full state.

**3rd** - `unknown`

Why is this `unknown`? What is this?

**4th** - `Action<string>`

Also didn't understand this. Why is `Action<T>` taking a string as a parameter? Should it always be `string`? Why is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the typings at https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/d28ab03fd1d2dd1de402928a9589857e97142e09/src/index.d.ts

```
/**
 * A "thunk" action (a callback function that can be dispatched to the Redux
 * store.)
 *
 * Also known as the "thunk inner function", when used with the typical pattern
 * of an action creator function that returns a thunk action.
 *
 * @template TReturnType The return type of the thunk's inner function
 * @template TState The redux state
 * @template TExtraThunkARg Optional extra argument passed to the inner function
 * (if specified when setting up the Thunk middleware)
 * @template TBasicAction The (non-thunk) actions that can be dispatched.
 */
export type ThunkAction<
  TReturnType,
  TState,
  TExtraThunkArg,
  TBasicAction extends Action
> = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>,
  getState: () => TState,
  extraArgument: TExtraThunkArg,
) => TReturnType;
```

**First** - **TReturnType**

Here we don't care about the return type - we're not waiting for the result of the thunk anyway. In TS it's ok to assign any function to a void signature, as it's not going to hurt type safety. [Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKAlMgfFAbnASwBMBuAKDIGM4A7AZ2CgDMEBBOkGygLlgWSgBDDlzSYkOAN5koUavTgAbCADpFcAOaoA5Czjb05AL4V5DZmxGUAcgFcAthABOBHn0QphnSmOxRpsmZKqupauggG5LJOEMC2TjRQAIwATADMxqa05nq88B6%20Ev4yctnBapo6epFkJhRAA) an example showing that I can assign various async/non-async functions to a void function signature:

[image: playground void assignment screenshot]

We use the provided dispatch function to trigger the next action we care about - so the only thing that matters in terms of timing is that internally to the async function we are awaiting certain things. Redux-thunk internally is not doing anything with the result of this function. Here's a great explainer on how thunks work under the hood (just the preview is necessary):

https://frontendmasters.com/courses/rethinking-async-js/synchronous-and-asynchronous-thunks/

**Second** - **TState**
Yep - this is the whole store state type

**Third - TExtraThunkARg**
You can add your own custom extra argument that gets passed into the thunk after dispatch and getState. This defaults to unknown, as unless you explicitly provide it then it's not clear what it will be. This is type safe, as trying to interact with an unknown argument will lead to compile time errors.

More here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument

**Fourth - TBasicAction**

This is an action type. Action is the most basic type of action - where every `type` property is a plain string. Optionally you can provide your own more specific types - i.e `type MyActionType = 'FOO_ACTION' | 'BAR_ACTION'` for further type safety/narrowing. You would then use this as Action.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, most of the answers can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.d.ts).

```
 * @template TReturnType The return type of the thunk's inner function
 * @template TState The redux state
 * @template TExtraThunkARg Optional extra argument passed to the inner function
 * (if specified when setting up the Thunk middleware)
 * @template TBasicAction The (non-thunk) actions that can be dispatched.
 */
export type ThunkAction<
  TReturnType,
  TState,
  TExtraThunkArg,
  TBasicAction extends Action
> = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>,
  getState: () => TState,
  extraArgument: TExtraThunkArg,
) => TReturnType;
```

**1st** - `void`

The return type of the thunk is **NOT** a `Promise`. It is just a function that returns an **inner** function. Since the **inner** function it does not return anything, the return type is `void`.

**2nd** - `RootState`

Yes that is correct. Refer to the above source code. Specifically, this line `* @template TState The redux state`.

**3rd** - `unknown`

You read about unknown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any).

**4th** - `Action<string>`

Refer to this line `* @template TBasicAction The (non-thunk) actions that can be dispatched.`

```
 * @template T the type of the action's `type` tag.
 */
export interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}
```

Code snippet is extracted from [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/types/actions.ts).

`Action<T>` accepts `string` type because the action type **IS** a `string`, and the `ThunkAction` type is expecting an `Action` type as seen here -  `TBasicAction extends Action`.

**CORRECTION**

**1st** - `void`

I had misunderstood and forgotten about `async` functions. See the first comment below.

Comment: I believe the explanation of point #1 is not quite right. Async functions do return promises by default - and you can see TS infer this in this example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEBBYUCW4YF4YEMICeYwMAFAJTYB8MA3gFAwyiQgA2ApgHRsgDmpAOS4ARsEHkA3PQC+9IA

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One last thing about the `3rd` item. I wasn't asking about what is the `unknown` type itself, but rather whay am I typing as `unkown` in the 3rd parameter? I've gone deeper into the source code and I think it's the type for the extra argument, when you initialize the thunk middleware as `applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api)),` for example. So you'll get `return (dispatch, getState, api)` in your thunks' "creators". It this is correct, you could add that to your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Rather - it's acceptable within TS to assign any function to a function type with return type void: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAKuaBeKAKAlFVA+KANzgEsATAbgCgqBjOAOwGdgoAzBAQVuBMYC5YCZJFxQAhkxANamHPigBvKlCj1mcADYQAdJrgBzDAHJxAI1rGs1VQCcIwAK62GSiYICMAJgDMUAL7U-lRAA

Comment: @mbdavis I agree with you. It's the return type for the actual `thunk`, which usually is `async` and not the `thunk` "creator". I think it's not mandatory that it should be `async`, is it? So, could we use `Promise<void> | void` ?

Comment: @cbdeveloper - yes you're right in both cases. It's for the thunk - not the thunk creator, and it's not mandatory to be async. Promise<void> would be a more accurate type here - but really it's just extra unnecessary complexity. Unless another part of your code requires the result of the function to be more specific (for example if redux-thunk internally cared about the fact that the function is a promise) - then there's no need to add the extra information.

Comment: @mbdavis you are spot on. I had forgotten all about `async` functions in `redux-thunk`. Thanks for pointing it out ;)

Comment: @cbdeveloper `unknown` is used for this API to signal “this can be any value, so you must perform some type of checking before you use it”. This forces users to safely introspect returned values.